# Python multiprocessing.Manager FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть следующий код:

```
import multiprocessing
import json
import time

class Process(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        with open("data.json") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            self.data = multiprocessing.Manager().dict(data)
            super().__init__(target = self.global_handler)

    def global_handler(self):
        print(self.data.get("users"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = Process()
    process.start()
```

При запуске интерпретатора выдаёт ошибку

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл.

Файл data.json содержит множество вложений словарей и списков. Показано на скриншоте: https://vk.cc/aC35Ad
Manager мне нужен для синхронизации данных между процессами.
Почему происходит эта ошибка? Как её исправить?

Comment: А если в `main` а не внутри `Process` таким же образом `json` загрузить, то ошибки нет?

Comment: Ошибка остаётся

Comment: Тогда `multiprocessing` вообще не при чём. У вас вероятно скрипт запускается не из того каталога, где лежит файл. Вернее, интерпретатор питона запускается так, что домашний каталог получается какой-то другой.

Comment: В какой папке лежит джейсон? Как запускается скрипт?

Comment: Json лежит в той же директории, что и скрипт. Он запускается из командой строки